# How to change img to amp-img with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, amp-html

Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) Project

Original

```
<div class="thumbnail"> 
 <img src="MyImage.jpg" alt="an image"/>
</div>
```

Result

```
<div class="thumbnail">
 <amp-img src="MyImage.jpg" width="1080" height="610" layout="responsive" alt="an image"></amp-img>
</div>
```

How to do it with jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) API to replace the content :

```
$('.thumbnail').find('img').replaceWith(function () {
   return '<amp-img src="'+this.src+'" width="1080" height="610" layout="responsive" alt="'+this.alt+'"></amp-img>'
});
```

Comment: how can you use jquery on amp pages, i have been searching for this, please guide me

Comment: @SaurabhSashank, you cannot use Javascript on AMP pages. There is no way to include JQuery. If you want to this conversion, it will have to be done server-side.